# Unable to test spring rest controller because of NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I'm writing a test in which I want to test the rest controller.
I'm mocking the service which is in the controller, but spring wants also the repository which is inside the service ...

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(AccountRestController.class)
public class AccountRestControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private PremiumAccountService service;

    AccountRequestResource resource = new AccountRequestResource(25d);
    PremiumAccount premiumAccount = new PremiumAccount("abc", "cba", LocalDateTime.now(), 25d);

    @Test
    public void testGetAccountWithAvailableGB() throws Exception {
       given(service.getAccountByGB(25d)).willReturn(Optional.of(premiumAccount));
       mockMvc.perform(post("/api/account"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.login", is("abc")));


    }

}
```

Stack :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'premiumaccountservice.repository.PremiumAccountRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
```

AccountRestController :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class AccountRestController {

    private final PremiumAccountService service;

    @Autowired
    public AccountRestController(PremiumAccountService service) {
        this.service= service;
    }

}
```

Comment: looks like an open issue. [github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6663]

Comment: Can you please post the full stacktrace and the code of `AccountRestController`? Could it be possible that you are injecting the `PremiumAccountRepository` into your `AccountRestController`?
Which spring version are you using?

Comment: @fap No, in `AccountRestController` the `PremiumAccountService ` is only injected. I'm using spring boot 1.5.6.RELEASE

Comment: Post the full stacktrace. Also show `PremiumAccountService`, and all the packages involved. One of the most common mistakes is not scanning the right packages.

Comment: did you fix it?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you forgot to add @Autowired annotation on your  service instance variable in rest controller.

Comment: constructor will handle the spring injection